# How to revert from 'mobile' site to 'desktop' site

Tags: support, mobile-web

While using SO I clicked on an icon which seemed to have directed me to the mobile version of the site.

Even after closing the browser and entering the URL again, I can't go to the desktop version of the site now. I can't find an icon to the desktop site either. Any help ?

This is what I get all the time :

[image]

Though the meta site works fine.

System : Linux | Chrome

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Click the "full site" link at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Comment: What _were_ you looking at in that other tab @Matt ? ;-P